# How to get a string part according to a width value?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, textbox, custom-controls

I have a custom rounded textbox and I don't want to write text to rounded parts so I want to know how much characters from the start of string reach a specified with. I know `TextRenderer.MeasureText` to measure a string, but it gives just a string's width, doesn't work reverse way. How can I do that?

I can do this but it can take much time sometimes.

```
    string resultText = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < Text.Length; i++)
    {
       resultString = Text.Substring(0, i);
       if (TextRenderer.MeasureText(resultText, Font).Width <= textWidth)
          break;
    }
```

Comment: what type of application is this? use proper tagging

Comment: This is a Windows Form Application

Comment: Unless you use a fixed width font, all characters will have different widths, so something like this is what you will need to do.

Comment: Your method is OK... you could probably syntatically reduce the for loop by `LINQ`, by I will say that your method is OK... of course you could do some sort of recursive "binary search" by starting to cut things from the middle and goes left or right depending on the width evaluation result too.. it is slightly more complicated but could possibly be a lot faster for long `string` (if your string is long). But if the `string` isn't that long, what you have done is most probably good enough.

Comment: @lan, I think so that, your way is better than using Brute-Force style. Using a recursively cutting into two parts , it can be much faster. I will add if I can do.

Comment: I have a better solution now and  written as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I have found a better solution without loop. In this method, we calculate a ratio between current width and target width. And if this ratio multiplied by the current length of string we get a good substring point.

```
 string GetSubStringToWidth(string orgText, int width, Font font)
    {
        int orgWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(orgText, font).Width;

        float ratio = (float)width / orgWidth;

        int length = (int)(orgText.Length * ratio);

        if (length >= orgText.Length) return orgText;
        else if (length <= 0) return "";
        else
        {
            //May be more sensitive if we go right or left one unit because of letter unequalities
            int mid = Math.Abs(width - TextRenderer.MeasureText(orgText.Substring(0, length), font).Width);
            int right = Math.Abs(width - TextRenderer.MeasureText(orgText.Substring(0, length + 1), font).Width);
            int left = Math.Abs(width - TextRenderer.MeasureText(orgText.Substring(0, length - 1), font).Width);

            int i = Math.Min(Math.Min(mid, right), left);
            int point = 0;

            if (i == mid)
                point = length;
            else if (i == right)
                point = length + 1;
            else
                point = length - 1;

            return orgText.Substring(0, point);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I doubt this will work well on all sorts of content. Also I doubt that your worries about timing have any real reason. 'Premature optimization is the root of all evil'. And of course cutting off text usually will result in, well, cut off text..

Comment: I have tested it just in my code. It has set the text middle of the textbox and that was what I want. I am not sure it will work well on all content but the better is better.